# Parse a JSON array into a data cell in a chart

Tags: arrays, json, charts, swiftui

I am trying to fitness data in a chart in SwiftUI for players in my sports team. Each player has an entry in a JSON file -

```
    [{
    "playerName": "AB",
    "id": 1075,
    "playerImage": "ainabrudy",
    "playerPosition": "Link",
    "playerDOB": "11/May/2002",
    "fiveKmRun": "[27.5, 32.5, 25.0, 20.7]",
    "broncoTimes": "[23.5, 28.5, 21.0, 39.7]",
    "glycoTimes": "[26.5, 23.5, 35.0, 33.7]"
}]
```

For the last 3 items I would like to parse the data into a chart struct replacing the static data -

```
    struct fivekmRun:View {
          var body: some View {
            VStack{
        LineView(data: [58,27,59,3,12,32,17,23,43], title: "5km Run Times", legend:          
              "2020").padding()
    }
    }
    }
```

The LineView just presents the static data in the data array. How to replace the static data with the JSON data for each individual player on their player detail view?

Comment: Check something like [this](https://github.com/AppPear/ChartView)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've solved the issue. The player JSON now reads as follows -

```
 [{
    "playerName": "AB",
    "id": 1075,
    "playerImage": "ainabrudy",
    "playerPosition": "Link",
    "playerDOB": "11/May/2002",
    "fiveKmRun": [27.5, 32.5, 25.0, 20.7],
    "broncoTimes": [23.5, 28.5, 21.0, 39.7],
    "glycoTimes": [26.5, 23.5, 35.0, 33.7]
}]
```

In the player data model, the "fiveKmRun", "broncoTimes", "glycoTimes" are now listed as -

```
    struct playerDataModel: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {

    ...
         var fiveKmRun: [Double]
         var broncoTimes: [Double]
         var glycoTimes: [Double]`
```

And now the chart gets its data as follows

```
struct fivekmRun:View {
var play: playerDataModel
          var body: some View {
            VStack{
        LineView(data: (player.fiveKmRun), title: "5km Run Times", legend: "2020").padding()
    }
    }
    }
```

Done.